# TensorFlow: Graph wide seeding and inter- and intra-op parallelism

Tags: concurrency, tensorflow, seeding

By using the `tf.set_random_seed()` method one can set the graph wide seed for random number generation.

However, I'm unsure whether/how this graph wide seed is working when multi-threaded execution is turned on by using `inter_op_parallelism_threads > 1` and `intra_op_parallelism_threads > 1` switches.

**Question:** After graph wide seeding using `tf.set_random_seed()` is the tensorflow random number generation process still deterministic when multiple operations are executed in parallel? Especially in the case when multiple random number generation ops are executed concurrently.

Comment: When you execute operations in parallel, then order of operations can be non-deterministic. IE, sess.run([q.enqueue(random_op),q.enqueue(random_op)]), it will be the same two numbers, but the order in which they get added to the queue is non-deterministic